# Strain field from multiple Displacements

Tags: matlab, math

I have a textfile that has three columns, the first one is x coordinates, the second one is y coordinates, and the third one is displacements. There are a couple thousand rows. The x and y coordinates are every constant number of meters. (example: [30 60 0.002; 60 90 0.001]). I am trying to calculate a strain field from these numbers. Is it enough for me to minus the displacement from one row by the displacement from the previous row and divide them by the distance between the two to get du/dx for normal strain in the x direction at that point (example: (.002-.001)/30)? I would then try to use contourf in matlab to get a visual representation of the field but if I do the whole minus thing I would get an odd number of values which I can't make a matrix out of. I am approaching my strain calculations wrong?

Comment: Which strain measure?  Green-Lagrange?  Euler-Almansi?  Cauchy?  Strain is a symmetric 2nd order tensor.  You need more than one component: You need six in 3D; three in 2D.

Comment: My advice is to fit a parametric model to the measurements and then calculate the strain from the model. This will have the advantage of smoothing out measurement noise, which is amplified by taking differences.